# Can not see source files in IntelliJ IDEA after cloning a project from Github

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

I cloned a project from Github from within IntelliJ IDEA but nothing shows up in the IDE. This is a Kotlin IntelliJ project that was automatically created on a different machine using the same version of the IDE. I import the project through the "Check out from version control" which is among the option presented when opening IntelliJ.  What am I missing? I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.5 on Windows 10 x64.

Comment: Your question is incomplete: Please describe how are you importing the project in IntelliJ. What project is this, Maven, Gradle, basic Java, Scala, Groovy etc

Comment: Verify the content/source roots configuration, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/content-root.html.

Comment: @CrazyCoder, I see nothing related to the project, neither source files nor directories.

Comment: So you need to configure the project again if it was not shared on GitHub.

Comment: What happens if you just run `git clone https://github.com/toyourproject`?